# How to pass a reference to a fixed-size array to constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I'm trying to pass a reference to a fixed-sized C-style array to a constructor. Here is my code:

```
#include <cstddef>

template <typename T, size_t size>
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(T (&arr)[size]);

    T (&m_arr)[size];
    size_t m_size;
};

Foo::Foo(T (&arr)[size])
  : m_arr {arr},
    m_size {size}
{}
```

Here are the build errors when trying to compile the above:

```
invalid use of template-name 'Foo' without an argument list
expected unqualified-id before ',' token
expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '{' token
expected unqualified-id before '{' token
```

Using the STL is not an option.

I'm using GNU v7.3.1 (Linaro).

Comment: That's not the proper syntax for defining members of class templates.

Comment: Refer to [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) where the first step is to "search and then research" and you'll find plenty of related SO posts for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the template parameters when defining (implementing) the `Foo` constructor:

```
template<typename T, size_t size>
Foo<T, size>::Foo(T (&arr)[size]) ...
```

Quite honestly, any decent beginners learning resource should have that information.

---

A perhaps easier solution would be to define the constructor inline in the class itself:

```
template<typename T, size_t size>
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(T (&arr)[size])
        : m_arr{ arr }, m_size{ size }
    {
    }

    // ...
};
```

By the way, you don't need the `m_size` member, as you already have the `size` template argument.